# Why does IntelliJ's scala console display question marks when I print greek characters?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, encoding

For example, I observe the following behavior:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 12.0.1).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> print("hi!")
hi!
scala> print("γεια!")
????!
```

How can I fix this?

when setting the `file.encoding` to `UTF-8` I get:

```
scala> sys.props("file.encoding")
res0: String = UTF-8

scala> print("γεια!")
????!
scala>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The point is that run/debug console uses the IDEA encoding. IDEA is a java application and encoding can be set in the idea.exe.vmoptions file as ordinary VM parameter. This file lies near your IDEA executabe file and conteins a set of JVM parameters. Add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 there to set encoding in UTF-8.

coming from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206290929-How-can-you-display-UTF-8-characters-in-the-Console-tab-

Answer (score 2):

Check if the `file.encoding` is set to `UTF-8` by running `Scala Console` and evaluate

```
sys.props("file.encoding")
```

If it does not return

```
res0: String = UTF-8
```

then stop and edit `Scala Console` run configuration. Under `VM Options` input field enter Unicode file encoding like so

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Now rerun `Scala Console` run configuration, re-evaluate `sys.props("file.encoding")` to make sure it says `UTF-8`, and then try `print("γεια!")` which should now output

```
scala> print("γεια!")
γεια!
```

Comment: Hm that's pretty strange, I still get the same behavior. The sys.props("file.encoding") was already set to UTF-8... I updated the original question with the output and a screenshot. Is there anything else I could do?